# Trouble with RESTful service returning String[] objects

Tags: java, string, rest, generics

I have developed a simple RESTful webservice that returns a String[] with info that it gets from a database. The thing is that I use netbeans and tend to use classes as clients to this webservice, as netbeans generates them automatically, and in this case I don't know how to handle what the webservice method is requesting. It has to do with Class generic classes, and I don't know what to do.
Here is the method from the webservice:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public String[] tramo(@QueryParam("tramo") String tramo) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance();
    Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.17.56.133:1521:TRACK", "oc","oc");
    Statement stmt=conexion.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery("select IDT.ROWID, IDT.ID_ID, IDT.ID_PST_ID, IDT.ID_UM_ID,IDT.ID_POS, IDT.ID_PULSOS, IDT.ID_LANZAR, TEL_FISKERNEL.TEL_COLOR_EXT, TEL_FISKERNEL.TEL_SEC_MONT,TEL_FISKERNEL.TEL_PRS_FAM,TEL_FISKERNEL.TEL_SORTENES_FAM from IDT,TEL_FISKERNEL where IDT.ID_UM_ID =  TEL_FISKERNEL.TEL_PIN and ID_PST_ID="+tramo+" order by ID_POS" );
    int i=0;
    while(rs1.next()){
        pin[i]=rs1.getString("ID_UM_ID");
        i++;
    }
    rs1.close();
    stmt.close();
    conexion.close();


    return pin;


}
```

As you can see it returns a simple String[] object, and that is what I would like to get when calling this method, but when netbeans creates the client, its method is written like this:

```
public <T> T tramo(Class<T> responseType, String tramo) throws ClientErrorException {
        WebTarget resource = webTarget;
        if (tramo != null) {
            resource = resource.queryParam("tramo", tramo);
        }
        return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(responseType);
    }
```

What should I give to this method to get a String[]? I have tried and read many tutorials online but I just don't understand what this method is requesting.
Thanks in advance fellas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T is a generic for the type you want to use so the invocation would be something like this

```
String[] resp = tramo(String[].class, tramo)
```

Comment: OH GOD BLESS YOU. I lost the entire morning yesterday trying to guess that. Now i'm getting some other kind of errors but that one is solved. Thank you very very much :D